# Spring security - how come I can only access pages as ROLE_ADMIN and not ROLE_USER?

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my application, I have a `SecurityConfiguration` class that has the following method:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    http.addFilterBefore(filter,CsrfFilter.class);

    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("ssoId")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()

        .authorizeRequests()

            // I admit that this section needs some work
            .antMatchers("/", "/home/**", "/alert/*", "/scheduler/*", "/agent/*", "/ftp/*", "/smtp/*", "/sql/*").access("hasRole('USER')")
            .antMatchers("/benefit/transport/*", "/contract/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/", "/home/*", "/alert/*", "/scheduler/*", "/agent/*", "/ftp/*", "/smtp/*", "/sql/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/benefit/transport/*", "/contract/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")

            .and()
                .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
            .and()
                .csrf()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
}
```

But as stated on the question, I my user has the ROLE_ADMIN privilege, access is normal throughout the application. But if he has only ROLE_USER, no pages are displayed.

What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achive with these lines?

```
.antMatchers("/", "/home/**", "/alert/*", "/scheduler/*", "/agent/*", "/ftp/*", "/smtp/*", "/sql/*").access("hasRole('USER')")
.antMatchers("/", "/home/*", "/alert/*", "/scheduler/*", "/agent/*", "/ftp/*", "/smtp/*", "/sql/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

Seems to me that you are overwriting your configuration here.. So the ADMIN role would overwrite the USER role here.

Comment: Well, this section needs some work. I intended to give different access to different profiles. ROLE_ADMIN would be able to access all the application, but ROLE_USER not. I understand both lines could be replaced by `.antMatchers("/", "/home/*", "/alert/*", "/scheduler/*", "/agent/*", "/ftp/*", "/smtp/*", "/sql/*").access("hasAnyRole('ADMIN','USER')")`